# Having control elements in a word header when document is restricted to work on

Tags: ms-word, editing, developer-tools

I am making a word dokuemnt with some freetext fields and i want to restrict the editing only to the control elements. Some of these control fields are in my header. As soon as I restrict the editing I cant access the free text fields in the header anymore.

The other free text fields in the document are useable though. Is this just not possible in word or am I doing something wron?

Have been googleing this problem but didnt find anything

Comment: This is a "how do I use Word?" question, not a "how do I solve this problem with my code?" question. I recommend posting on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.